# How to get Values in String Array from XML in android

Tags: android, arrays

I have a String value in a variable for eg ID

XML Like

```
<DocumentElement><Contact ID="1" Name="Test1" 1/><Contact ID="2" Name="TEST" /></DocumentElement>
```

i get my id in _s2

i want to add all id in a  String Array like EmailArr

i have Done

```
Count=0;
EmailArr=new String[Count];

                String _s2=event.getAttribute("ID").getValue();

                if(_s2=="" || _s2==null){
                    _s2="N/A";
                }

                if(_s2!=null){
                    EmailArr[Count]=_s2;
                    Count=Count++;
                }
```

I get Exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Post the full code. what is event here?

Comment: event is the xml which i am parsing i get the correct vale in my _s2 Variable i want to add these values in Array

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Array with Xml Values:-

```
int count=XMlData.getPropertyCount();// Get the XML Data count/ some thing related to get  Count of XMl Details


    EmailArr=new String[Count]; // create Array EmailArr with that Count
```

Comment: Error becuse u are intialize array with 0 Index, you are trying to add Element for Index 1, thats why exception occurs

Comment: How to get the property count for the  xml  like you have written         int count=XMlData.getPropertyCount();

Comment: Here am using SOAP response form .NEt Web Service, so that I can able to use getPropertyCount() method, If you have XMl Data, there will be Count(), to get the count Properties, Error is becuse you need to create Array using that Count

Comment: int count=response.getPropertyCount();
            
            for(int i=0;i<count; ++i)
            {
               SoapObject p= (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
             
                listProducts.add(new Contatc(Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty(0).toString()),p.getProperty(1).toString()));
                  
              
            }
      some thing like this we can use to get List<Contact>

Answer (score 0):

You should give some initial size to your array :

```
EmailArr=new String[Count];//where count is number of records
```

Comment: You can't give zero otherwise array size will be zero. Try with some other values.